# Correct Specification of IPTW Estimator

Tags: causality, propensity-scores

As in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21525/inverse-probability-of-treatment-weighted-iptw-estimator-for-a-binary-outcome/304231#304231), my understanding of the standard IPTW estimator is that it is
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_i \frac{Y_i T_i}{\hat{e}_i} - \frac{Y_i (1 -T_i)}{1 -
 \hat{e}_i}$$

This can straightforwardly be shown to unbiasedly estimate the Average Treatment Effect (ATE) when the propensity score model is correctly specified, as [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4285308/) does. However, in equation 2, section 2.3, that [same paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4285308/) specifies the IPTW estimator differently:
$$\sum_i \frac{Y_i T_i}{\hat{e}_i} (\sum_i \frac{T_i}{\hat{e}_i})^{-1} - \sum_i \frac{Y_i (1 -T_i)}{1 -\hat{e}_i} (\sum_i \frac{1 - T_i}{1 - \hat{e}_i})^{-1}$$

I've run some simulations:

```
expit <- function(x) exp(x) / (1 + exp(x))

p <- 0.05
n <- 1e4
x <- cbind(rnorm(n), rexp(n), rbeta(n, 5, 5))
# t <- rbinom(n, 1, p)
t <- rbinom(n, 1, expit(x%*%c(-3,1,0)))
y <- 5*t + x%*%c(4,2,6) + rnorm(n)

prop <- glm(t ~ x[,1] + x[,2] + x[,3], family = binomial)
ps <- predict(prop, type = 'response')

iptw0 <- sum(y[t == 0] / (1 - ps[t == 0]))/n
iptw0
mean(y[t == 0])
weird0 <- sum(y[t == 0] / (1 - ps[t == 0]))/sum(1/(1 - ps[t == 0]))
weird0
iptw1 <- sum(y[t == 1] / ps[t == 1])/n
iptw1
mean(y[t == 1])
weird1 <- sum(y[t == 1] / ps[t == 1])/sum(1/ps[t == 1])
weird1

iptw1 - iptw0
weird1 - weird0
```

and both estimators appear to do perform well. Can anyone reconcile the two or provide references for the latter "weird" estimator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first estimator is the Horvitz-Thompson estimator. The second estimator is the Hájek Estimator --- basically you are normalizing/stabilizing
 the weights to gain efficiency (but it's not guaranteed you will gain efficiency). You can read more about them in survey sampling books.